# NodeJS - C/C++ Addon communication (stdin stdout)

Tags: c++, c, node.js

I am trying to pass an audio stream to C/C++ Addon. But first I want to understand and implement some basic examples. The whole objective is to use stdin and stdout to pipe information between nodeJS and the addon.
In nodejs I can see the stdout with this code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readableStream = fs.createReadStream('file.txt');
var data = '';

readableStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data+=chunk;
});

readableStream.on('end', function() {
    console.log(data);
});
```

But now, How can I pass it to c/c++ addon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass data directly from NodeJS to C++. You can write/develop your own Node addon/module in C++ which exposes some functions to (Node) JS then pass the data to these functions:

```
var myModule = require('mymodule'); // The Node addon you wrote    
myModule.processData(data);
```

Now, `processData` receives data from JS and it is a C++ implementation so there you go.

Comment: Where can I find the information to implement that module? (in other words, How can I "processData"?)

Comment: Ok, now I understand what are you saying. I already have an addon, now I will try to find a way to interpret the information from nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of creating a native addon in Linux. Hope this helps:

```
#include <node.h>
using namespace v8;

void foo(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {

// extract the parameter(s)
int value = args[0]->NumberValue();
// do stuff with value.

//optionally, return a value.
args.GetReturnValue().Set(value + 10);
}


void init(Handle<Object> exports) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "processData", foo);
}
NODE_MODULE(addon, init)
```

Build: Linux (ia32):
g++  -I./deps/v8/include  -I./src -shared -m32 -o mymodule.node mymodule.cc

1. NODE_MODULE macro directs node to register amodule named 'mymodule' and export a method called 'processData' which is internally mapped to 'foo'
2. This makes the handshake between JS space and the C++ space for method calls.
3. Now you can make a call to 'processData' as suggested marekful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming nodejs script:

```
var addon = require('./build/Debug/addon.node');
var fs = require('fs');
var readableStream = fs.createReadStream('file.txt');
var data = '';

readableStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data+=chunk;
});

readableStream.on('end', function() {
    console.log("loaded");
    console.log('addon invocation:', addon.read_stream(data));
});
```

This script can load the file information:

```
#include <node.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace v8;
using namespace std;

void read_stream(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
  HandleScope scope(isolate);

  if (args.Length() < 1) {
    isolate->ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(
        String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Wrong number of arguments")));
    return;
  }

  v8::String::Utf8Value param1(args[0]->ToString());
  std::string auxiliar = std::string(*param1); //JS---->C++

}


void Init(Handle<Object> exports) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "read_stream", read_stream);
}

NODE_MODULE(addon, Init)
```

In the debug "auxiliar" string will have the text of "file.txt". Now its time to try with wav files.